# NSPredicate keeps crashing my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I've created a SearchBar thats suppose to filter a UITableView I have setup. I'm using Parse.com to pull this array down into my app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     [self Query];

     //[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SearchCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchData"];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)Query {
     PFQuery *Q = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];

     [Q selectKeys:@[@"username"]];

     [Q findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
              NSLog(@"load Array);
              SearhArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];    
         }
         else{ 
             NSLog(@"Array No Good");
         }
       }];
}
```

Then I attempt to filter the array Using these lines of code

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
     self.searchTerm = searchText;
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     [self.mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
     //reset to the original array and reload table
     self.filteredCities = SearhArray;
     [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     [self.mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];

     if ([self.searchTerm isEqualToString:@""]) {
         // Nothing to do here - Reset to the original array and reload table
         self.filteredCities = SearhArray;
     } else {
         // Filter the array based on the term searched for using a predicate
         NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.title contains[c] %@",self.searchTerm];
         self.filteredCities = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[SearhArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
     }
     [self.myTableView reloadData];
} 

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     self.filteredCities = SearhArray;
     [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

But it just keeps crashing. I've debugged the problem down to this line

```
self.filteredCities = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[SearhArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

The error I get is:

```
`2015-03-31 19:31:19.783 Pondu[59307:5149459] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "words" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18724a59c 0x1979a00e4 0x18724a4dc 0x1000c34bc 0x1880350f0 0x18807b934 0x18807b394 0x18807a084 0x188079e58 0x1000b31b0 0x18be207ac 0x18ba30d34 0x18ba19e48 0x18bbf91dc 0x18bbc3f04 0x18bd80890 0x18bd80540 0x18ba24950 0x18811ddf0 0x1872029ec 0x187201c90 0x1871ffd40 0x18712d0a4 0x1902cf5a4 0x18ba623c0 0x1000b1f64 0x19800ea08)
Libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`
```

Comment: your crash is happening elsewhere, probably where you are fetching the data from parse and/or your local coredata store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.searchTerm seems like NSString but what you are put there is you are supposing that value as NSDictionary. You need to use something like

> @"SELF MATCHES %@"

, NOT

> @"SELF.title MATCHES %@"

Comment: the app stopped crashing but the tableview is coming up blank. so I added an NSLog to see why          NSLog(@"%@",predicate);    Its returning this...  2015-03-31 20:21:20.610 Pondu[59863:5164017] SELF MATCHES nil

Comment: can you please check self.searchTerm? it is not nil?

Comment: its returning this .. 2015-03-31 20:37:10.088 Pondu[60019:5168434] (null)

Comment: if ([searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
         // Nothing to do here - Reset to the original array and reload table
         self.filteredCities = SearhArray;
     } else {
         // Filter the array based on the term searched for using a predicate
         NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchBar.text];
         self.filteredCities = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[SearhArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
     }

Comment: 2015-04-01 15:00:38.882 Pondu[66770:5397570] <UISearchBar: 0x15c56b1a0; frame = (0 0; 375 44); text = 'wadza'; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1702598f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x17042b6e0>>
2015-04-01 15:00:38.884 Pondu[66770:5397570] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <PFUser:OrNIQ2rknK:

Comment: (null)> {
    FullName = "Wadzaire Blanc";
    photo = "<PFFile: 0x174463080>";
    username = wadza;
} (not a collection)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18724a59c 0x1979a00e4 0x18817327c 0x18807be58 0x18807b3ec 0x18807a084 0x188079e58 0x1000731b8 0x18be207ac 0x18ba30d34 0x18ba19e48 0x18bbf91dc 0x18bbc3f04 0x18bd80890 0x18bd80540 0x18ba24950 0x18811ddf0 0x1872029ec 0x187201c90 0x1871ffd40 0x18712d0a4 0x1902cf5a4 0x18ba623c0 0x100071ad4 0x19800ea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you please change your contain predicate? what about change it to SELF MATCHES %@

Comment: Don't worry I already fixed. I changed it to "username contains[c] %@". Thank you for all your help!